# Does there exist any $C^{\infty}$-function with the following property?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Does there exists a $C^{\infty}$ function $f : \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) = 1,$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ with $|x| \lt 1$ and $f(x) = 0,$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ with $|x| \gt 5\ $?

If the answer is "yes" can anybody give me some hint as to how to construct such a function? Any help in this regard will be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of bump functions?

Comment: Holly wikipedia: [Bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)

Answer (score 1):

With a $C^\infty$ helper function $h\colon\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that $h(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and $h(x)>0$ for $x>0$, you can easily construct such and similar examples.
For example,
$$g(x):= \frac{h(x+1)}{h(5-x)+h(x+1)}$$
(note that the denominator is always $>0$!) has the property that $g(x)=0$ for $x\ge5$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x\le 1$. Then
$$ f(x):=g(x)g(-x)$$
has your desired property.

---

Remains to find a suitable $h$. Here, $e^{-\frac1x}$ is your friend.

Comment: How do you get that $g(x) = 0,$ for $x \geq 5\ $? What I observe is that $$g(x)=0 \iff h(x+1) = 0 \iff x+1 \leq 0 \iff x \leq -1.$$

Comment: I think what you want to mean is that $$g(x) = \dfrac {h(5-x)} {h(5-x) + h(x-1)}.$$ Am I right?

Comment: Also I don't get your point as to how $e^{-\frac {1} {x}}$ suits my purpose. It is not defined at $0.$